# Error al intentar modificar el comportamiento de un **for**

Tags: java, bucle-for

He hecho este código para resolver un ejercicio, el mismo requiere llenar un array de longitud nueve, con números aleatorios (que no se repitan), con valores entre 1 y 10, ambos contenidos, esto implica que un numero no se puede agregar, se debe llenar el array, e identificar el número que quedo afuera.
El codigo es bastante simple, se crea el array **bolsa** en el que se guardaran los números, y el array **control**, que uso para identificar el número faltante.
el **for** externo itera sobre **bolsa**, y genera un aleatorio, luego (si **i** != 0) se entra el el **for** interno.
En el interno, el **if** compara el aleatorio con los números almacenados en **bolsa**, si no encuentra coincidencias, se sale del bulce y se agregan los datos a los array corespondientes, si hay coincidencias, dentro del **if** se re-genera el aleatorio y se resetea **k**, el problema es que la primera iteración después de eso, no pasa por el **if**, por lo tanto si en esa primera iteración hay coincidencia, el numero repetido va al array de salida (bolsa), no logro entender porque hace ese salto.
El problema ya lo resolví... modifique el código, pero quiero saber que es lo que está mal en mi razonamiento.

Notas:
probé con **k = -1**, lo que obviamente me lanzó un error.
coloque etiquetas... **en todos lados**, pero no modificaban el comportamiento.
el salto se produce aunque no se haya llegado al límite (el valor de **i**).

```
  public void cosa( String[] args ) {
      int piezas = 10;
      if( piezas >= 3 ) {
         piezas--;
         int[] bolsa = new int[ piezas ];
         int control[] = new int[ piezas ];
         for( int i = 0; i < piezas; i++ ) {
            int ran = (int) ( Math.random() * piezas + 1 );
            for( int k = 0; k < i; k++ ) {
               if( ran == bolsa[ k ] ) {
                  ran = (int) ( Math.random() * piezas + 1 );
                  k = 0;
               }
            }
            bolsa[ i ] = ran;
            control[ ran - 1 ] = 1;
         }
         for( int i = 0; i < control.length; i++ ) {
            if( control[ i ] == 0 ) {
               System.out.println( "falta la pieza " + ( i + 1 ) );
               return;
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Especifico una condición del for interno bajo la cual... falla?.

```
for( int k = 0; k < i; k++ ) {  
    System.out.print( ran + " " + bolsa[ k ] );
    if( ran == bolsa[ k ] ) {
        ran = (int) ( Math.random() * piezas + 1 );
            k = 0;
        }
     }
}
```

en determinado momento tengo (por ejemplo):
** bolsa = [ 2, 8, 7, 5 ]**

```
**i = 5,  k = 3,  ran = 5 bolsa[ k ] = 5**
```

el programa entra al **if**, dentro del mismo, cambía a:

```
**ran = 2, k = 0**
```

según mi lógica, debería volver a entrar el el **if**, ya que:

```
**ran = 2, k = 0 y bolsa[ k ] = 2**
```

no es que no entra en el **if** tampoco pasa por **System.out**.

Una de las pruebas:

```
int k = 0
volver:
for( ; k < i; k++ ) {
    if( ran == bolsa[ k ] ) {
        ran = (int) ( Math.random() * piezas + 1 );
        k = 0;
        break volver;
    }
}
```

Aca también, si el numero generado dentro del **if** es igual a **bolsa[ 0 ]... no lo detecta.

Comment: Proba poniendo k <= i en el for interior.  En la primera iteración el for exterior tiene i=0, y cuando llega al for interior k tiene el valor inicial 0. La condición para que el for interior se ejecute es que k sea menor a i en tu ejemplo, y en la primera iteración eso no se cumple, k e i son iguales. Perdón por no darte una mejor respuesta, no puedo probar tu código en este momento.

Comment: El caso es mas complicado, por ejemplo, teniendo **i = 4**, yo llevo  a **k = 0**, y no pasa por el **if**... y nada que disculpar, gracias por haber contestado!!.

Comment: Pues quizá la condición de ese if no se esté cumpliendo, prueba imprimir las variables k y ran dentro del for interior pero fuera del if, así ves que valor tienen antes de llegar a el. Por cierto dentro del if pones k=0 que significa eso? Querés reiniciar el bucle?

Comment: @infinit3Loop__, exactamente quiero reiniciar el loop, agregué en la pregunta una de las condiciones donde mi lógica parece fallar...

Comment: hola podrias hacer una función para que llene el arreglo con los numeros aleatorios, una vez lleno creas otra para verificar que no se repitan los numeros lo colocas dentro de un bucle y hasta que la funcion de la condición esperada no pare de llenar el arreglo, luego de que no se repitan los numeros podrias crear otra funcion para que revize el numero que falta.

Comment: Hola @francox17, gracias por el aporte, como dije en la pregunta, el ejercicio ya lo solucioné, la pregunta es porque no puedo **resetear** el array, osea, si lo reseteo, pero no desde el valor **i = 0**, siempre recomienza en **i = 1**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que quieres hacerlo de forma algorítmica, sin métodos de arrays y eso. En este caso el array control no lo uso, aprovecho el factorial de 10 para hacer una resta que me obtenga el numero faltante, los bucles while/do-while en combinación con las sentencias break y continue son excelentes para iteraciones que no sabemos cuándo pueden terminar:

```
int[] bolsa = new int[9]; 
int excluded = 0;
boolean exists;
int sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < bolsa.length; i++){ // recorriendo bolsa para llenarlo
  do{ // este do while no se detendra a menos que se le asigne a bolsa[i] un numero que no exista en dicho array
    int ran = (int) ( Math.random() * 10 + 1 ); 
    exists = false; // el valor por defecto de exists es false
    for(int h = 0; h < i; h++){ // para cada elemento de bolsa (ya llenado)
      if(bolsa[h] != ran) continue; // si se cumple, continua con la siguiente interacion del for (las 2 lineas de abajo no se ejecutan)
      exists = true; // si no pasa por el continue entonces exists es true, usamos break para salir del for
      break;
    }
    if(!exists) { // si exists quedo en false despues de pasar por el for entonces ya podemos llenar bolsa con el valor no repetido
      bolsa[i] = ran;
      sum += ran; // esto es para obtener la suma de los valores que coloquemos en bolsa, que nos servira mas adelante
    } 
  } while(exists); // si por el contrario exists quedo en true, el do while volvera a iterar, generando un nuevo aleatorio y asi sucesivamente
}

excluded = 55 - sum; // si le resto a la suma de los numeros de bolsa, obtengo el faltante

System.out.print("Array bolsa: - ");
for(int k=0;k<bolsa.length;k++){ // imprimiendo bolsa
  System.out.print(bolsa[k] + " - ");
}

System.out.println();
System.out.print("Numero excluido: " + excluded); // imprimiendo faltante
```

Intente comentar todo, espero que no te resulte confuso. Ah y si queres reiniciar un bucle lo mejor es usar while/do-while. Acá tenes un artículo de como [reiniciar un for en java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766910/is-there-a-loop-start-over)

**EDIT**

Acá tenes un ejemplo de cómo reiniciar un for, este simplemente recorre un array, si el número es < 10 le da el valor 10 y reinicia el for, así hasta que no queden más números menores a 10.

```
int[] myarr = new int[]{12, 56, 7, 12, 4, 12};

for( int i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++ ){
  System.out.println("valor de i: " + i);
  if(myarr[i] < 10){
    System.out.println("valor donde se reseteo el for: " + myarr[i]);
    myarr[i] = 10;
    i = -1;
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: eres un **grosso**, tomo nota de como lo has realizado y guardo el enfoque, es muy bueno... pero como dice la pregunta, el ejercicio ya lo resolví, lo que necesito es entender cual es el error de mi intento de resetear el array, osea **porque no puedo volver la "i" cero?**. igual muchas gracias por tu atención.

Comment: Para resetearlo intenta poner i=-1; continue;

Comment: lo intente, y me arroja el error esperable.

Comment: Ahí te agregue un ejemplo simple a mi respuesta, a mí me funciona con continue -1 ya lo probe. Si te sirve márcala como útil.

Comment: ya lo habia probado y me devolvía un error... ahora funcionaaa!!! gracias totales!! por tu dedicación.